# Writing the output of a python supervisory script from the console to a file

Tags: python, shell, scripting

I have a python script that will execute all of the python files in a folder that is a level below it.  Each of these files writes a status to the console about what it is testing and if it passed/failed and how long it took.  Is there a way to have the script that executes the tests also record the status that the test write to the console?   Thanks in advance.

Currently ::

Supervisor script > Runs Test Scripts > Test Scripts output status

What I am trying to do ::

Supervisor script > Runs Test Scripts > Test Scripts output status > Supervisor script writes previous step to a file

Answer (score 0):

I would use python's logging library:

```py
import logging

# setup log name. default location is the same as the script
logging.basicConfig(filename="master.log")

script_output = "sample output"
print(script_output)
logging.info(script_output)
```

See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html) for more info